# Retrieve two properties using <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am displaying two values in JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>` and want to retrieve both values in managed bean. following is my JSF code.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Product "/>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{placeOrderController.placeOrder.product}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{itemController.itemList}" var="cs" itemLabel="#{cs.title}  - #{cs.price}" itemValue="#{cs.title}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In above code, I am displaying two values in  `<f:selectItems>`, which are `title` and `price`, seperated by `"-"`. I am successfully getting `title` in managed bean but wondering that how can I get `price` value too.

Comment: No, if i try this one then both value will come together. how would i separate those ones then ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your last comment. Don't you need to display something like "Item Title 1 - 200", "Item Title 2 - 450" and on in a dropdownlist (`<h:selectOneMenu>`)?

Comment: Thats what i am doing currently. Display both values but getting only title in managed bean. i want to get both values in managed bean.

Comment: Ok now I understand your problem. This can be easily solved if you use a converter. This is covered in [StackOverflow selectonemenu wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Try to set unique value by which you can identify both's mapping, e.g. unique relation no. Once the selection is changed then you can query the database to find out both value.